# How to animate widget when being deleted from listview.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

My app's home page has a listview of a bunch of images posted by users. Each widget takes up most of the screen so the others aren't visible. I have the widgets wrapped in a dismissable widget so when a user swipes right or left on a one, it is removed and the next one in the list pops up from below. This works as expected but I want to make it so that, when a widget is being dragged/dismissed, it distorts to look like it's flipping in the direction it's being dragged in. I know I need an animated container to do that but is it possible to do with the code I have:

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: posts.length,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final postImage = posts[index];
                  return Dismissible(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    child: Post(postImage),
                    onDismissed: (direction) {
                      setState(() {
                        posts.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ),
```